# PyQt4 QAbstractListModel - Only first data widget is displayed

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4, model-view

I'm trying to implement the `QAbstractListModel` class in order to display several similar widgets.
The following code shows my problem:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QtCore.QAbstractListModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._widgets = []


    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        """ Returns header for columns """
        return "bla"


    def rowCount(self, parentIndex=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        """ Returns number of interfaces """
        return len(self._widgets)


    def data(self, index, role):
        """ Returns the data to be displayed """
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            return self._widgets[row]


    def insertRow(self, widget, parentIndex=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        """ Inserts a row into the model """
        self.beginInsertRows(parentIndex, 0, 1)
        self._widgets.append(widget)
        self.endInsertRows()


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, name="None"):
        super(QtGui.QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.checkbox = QtGui.QCheckBox()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText(name)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkbox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.view = QtGui.QListView(self)
        self.model = Model()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        self.model.insertRow(
            widget=Widget(self)
        )
        self.model.insertRow(
            widget=Widget(self)
        )
        self.model.insertRow(
            widget=Widget(self)
        )
        self.model.insertRow(
            widget=Widget(self)
        )

        self.show()


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It works, there are four clickable entries in the list, but in only one of them the widget is actually displayed. Why is that?

I guess this behaviour is either caused by `data()` or how I'm using `beginInsertRows()`, but I can't figure out where the error is.

---

`ìnsertRow()` function now looks like that

```
def insertRow(self, widget, parentIndex=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
    """ Inserts a row into the model """
    self.beginInsertRows(parentIndex, len(self._widgets), len(self._widgets))
    self._widgets.append(widget)
    self.endInsertRows()
```

but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the four widgets are displayed. The issue is, they're all displayed in the top left corner. You can see they overlap if you put names, here "1", "2", "3", "4":

[image]

Fixing the row numbers doesn't solve the issue. The widgets  will be in the correct rows but will still be displayed on the top left. It is because `data` is supposed to [return text for the display role](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum).

To display simple widgets, I suggest using `QListWidget` and the [setItemWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget) method. Otherwise you'll have to use delegates.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try `QListWidget` then.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.beginInsertRows(parentIndex, 0, 1)
```

0 - start
1 - end

You refresh only first row during insert

```
self.beginInsertRows(parentIndex, len(self._widgets), len(self._widgets))
```

must be work. Don't remember this method

```
self.model.reset()
```

this refresh all list, without specific rows

Comment: I changed this line in my code and added `self.model.reset()` at the end of `Window` `__init__()`, but it still does not work.